# Custom Control returning task from another function Picker Control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am developing a Custom Control part of dialog kit fork however I am having a bit of trouble here.

I have included item source as a property of the constructor which works but my question is how do I pass back the value of the picker control to the constructor.

```
public PickerView(string title, string message, IEnumerable ItemSource, string text = null, Keyboard keyboard = null)
{
        InitializeComponent();

        txtInput.Text = text;
        BindTexts(title, message);
        txtInput.Keyboard = keyboard;
        pickItems.ItemsSource = ItemSource.Cast<object>().ToList();
        pickItems.SelectedIndexChanged += PickItems_SelectedIndexChanged;
 }
```

The way the control is instantiated is through the interface of

```
Task<T> GetPickerChoice<T>(string title, string message, IEnumerable ItemSource, string currentText = null,
Keyboard keyboard = null);
```

I want to be able to get the result that the user has selected out of the xamrian picker control which gets set in this event

```
private void PickItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I need some way of passing the result back to the way it is initiated this I pass in a list as follows.

```
   List<PickerModel> _testList = new List<PickerModel>();
   PickerModel model = new PickerModel();
   model.Value = 1008;
   model.Description = "FW";
  _testList.Add(model);
  var returnValueFromPicker= await Plugin.DialogKit.CrossDiaglogKit.Current.GetPickerChoice<PickerModel>("Fuel", $"This item is in one or more bins please select a bin location", _testList, null, Keyboard.Numeric);
```

I want the value of the picker to be in the value of returnValueFromPicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding an event handler

```
public event EventHandler<string> Picked;
```

To which when the person clicked the ok button of the popup I basically invoked it and returned the selected item for the control in case anyone else finds this usefull.

```
private void Confirm_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Picked?.Invoke(this, pickItems.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, you could marked it. This will make answer searching easier and beneficial to community members.

Answer (score 0):

You could have also added a bindable command to your PickerView. With that approach, you can bind ViewModel's command to it (if you use MVVM pattern).

To do that, you may want to add

```cs
public static BindableProperty ConfirmedCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: nameof(ConfirmedCommand),
    returnType: typeof(ICommand),
    declaringType: typeof(YourPickerClass),
    defaultValue: null);

public ICommand ConfirmedCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ConfirmedCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ConfirmedCommandProperty, value); }
}
```

to your picker. Then you can bind on a view layer.